# How to set start and end time of live video playback in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-media3

*Hi, I have a live TV show that starts at 08:00 and ends at 10:00, can I set the start and end time of the TV show for the DefaultTimeBar ?*

*Tried :*

`exoPlayerProgress.setDuration(60_000)`

*and*

```
MediaItem.Builder()
    .setUri(mUrl)
    .setLiveConfiguration(
        MediaItem.LiveConfiguration.Builder()
            .setMaxPlaybackSpeed(1.02f)
            .setTargetOffsetMs(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setMinOffsetMs(System.currentTimeMillis()-1800000)
            .setMaxOffsetMs(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000)
            .build()
    )
    .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_M3U8)
    .build()
```

*Full manifest*

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:5367
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2023-08-17T09:49:39Z
#EXTINF:10, no desc
segment-1692212102-005367.ts
#EXTINF:10, no desc
segment-1692212102-005368.ts
#EXTINF:10, no desc
segment-1692212102-005369.ts
#EXTINF:10, no desc
segment-1692212102-005370.ts
#EXTINF:10, no desc
segment-1692212102-005371.ts
#EXTINF:10, no desc
segment-1692212102-005372.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your Backend is sending timeline information info in HLS manifest.

If the stream start time is 0, then you can add offset value to show in UI.

```
tranformedContentDuration = 8*60*60 + player.contentPosition
```

`setMinOffsetMs` and `setMaxOffsetMs` serve different purpose. They are used by player to determine what is the ideal live edge.

Comment: It's bad that it's impossible to set a timestamp for the start and end of progress.